# I am trying to upload a image on instagram using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller, instagram-api

After handling the notification I want to click on this create
then select an image and after that next button
help me out I want to upload photos on Instagram.

My Code
`def upload_images(username, password, image_folder):
waitTime = 12

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

# Specify the path to chromedriver.exe
s = Service('chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

# Login to Instagram
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
time.sleep(3)

username_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
password_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')

username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input.send_keys(password)
password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
waitTime = random.randint(5, 10)
time.sleep(waitTime)

# Visit the user's account page
driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{username}')
waitTime = random.randint(5, 10)
time.sleep(waitTime)

# Go back to the Instagram homepage
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
waitTime = random.randint(5, 10)
time.sleep(waitTime)

# Handle the notification popup
# Handle the notification popup
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click()
    print("Not Now ")

except:
    pass

# Get a list of all image files in the folder
image_files = [file for file in os.listdir(image_folder) if file.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'))]

for image_file in image_files:
    image_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(image_folder, image_file))
    print(image_path)
    # Upload the image
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
    time.sleep(2)
    # find input field
    upload_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
    # send image
    upload_btn.send_keys(image_path)
    print("Upload Button Works")
    # Wait for the upload to complete
    button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), 'Next')]")
    button.click()
    # WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button' and text()='Next']")))

    # Click the first "Next" button
    next_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button' and text()='Next']")
    next_btn.click()

    # Wait for the second screen to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//element_on_second_screen")))

    # Click the second "Next" button on the second screen
    second_next_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button' and text()='Next on Second Screen']")
    second_next_btn.click()

    # Wait for the "Write a caption" input field to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@aria-label='Write a caption…']")))

    share_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='button' and text()='Share']")
    share_btn.click()

    print("Image uploaded successfully.")
```

`

But as soon as it handles notification it stops working
[image]
After handling the notification I want to click on this create
then select an image and after that next button
help me out I want to upload photos on Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem, you want to click on the create button and then click the "select from Computer" button on the modal.

The xpath `//input[@type='file']` is not a child of the **create** div element that you could be able to send your image path directly.

Try

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "_aacl _aacp _adda _aacx _aada")]').click()
```

you should get the below modal
[image: Create button]

You should be able to select from Computer by now